# Android Studio SQLite Cursor

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I started to learn SQLite in Android Studio. And I decided to make a simple registration. But now I have some problems. When I run program and enter some datas(like name, email and password). It crashed. Android monitor shows me this part of code(where is cursor). I don't know why on this part of code my app crashed? Please help me. Thanks.

Here it is this code:

```
public boolean isEmailExists(String email) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    String[] columns = {KEY_ID};
    String selection = KEY_EMAIL + " =?";
    String[] selectionArgs = {email};
    Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_NAME, columns, selection, selectionArgs, null, null, null);

    if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()&& cursor.getCount()>0) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

And this part when try to login. Both code are similar a little:

```
public User Authonticate(User user) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_NAME, new String[] {KEY_ID, KEY_USER_NAME, KEY_EMAIL, KEY_PASSWORD},
            KEY_EMAIL + "=?", new String[]{user.email}, null, null, null);
    if(cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst() && cursor.getCount()>0) {
        User user1 = new User(cursor.getString(0), cursor.getString(1), cursor.getString(2), cursor.getString(3));
        if(user.password.equalsIgnoreCase(user1.password)) {
            return user1;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

And this is full code:

```
package com.example.lado.banksystem;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;


/**
   * Created by lado on 21/3/18.
*/

public class DBHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "banksystem.db";
    public static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    public static final String TABLE_NAME = "banksystem";
    public static final String KEY_ID = "id";
    public static final String KEY_USER_NAME = "username";
    public static final String KEY_EMAIL = "email";
    public static final String KEY_PASSWORD = "password";

    public DBHandler(Context context, String name, SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory factory, int version) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        String query = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + "( " + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "
            + KEY_USER_NAME + " TEXT, " + KEY_EMAIL + " TEXT, " + KEY_PASSWORD + " TEXT " + ")";
        db.execSQL(query);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int i, int i1) {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME);
        onCreate(db);
    }

    public void addUser(User user) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(KEY_USER_NAME, user.userName);
        values.put(KEY_EMAIL, user.email);
        values.put(KEY_PASSWORD, user.password);
        db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, values);
        db.close();
    }

    public User Authonticate(User user) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_NAME, new String[] {KEY_ID, KEY_USER_NAME, KEY_EMAIL, KEY_PASSWORD},
            KEY_EMAIL + "=?", new String[]{user.email}, null, null, null);
         if(cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst() && cursor.getCount()>0) {
             User user1 = new User(cursor.getString(0), cursor.getString(1), cursor.getString(2), cursor.getString(3));
             if(user.password.equalsIgnoreCase(user1.password)) {
                 return user1;
             }
         }
         return null;
    }

    public boolean isEmailExists(String email) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        String[] columns = {KEY_ID};
        String selection = KEY_EMAIL + " =?";
        String[] selectionArgs = {email};
        Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_NAME, columns, selection, selectionArgs, null, null, null);

        if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()&& cursor.getCount()>0) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

This is error

```
3-21 21:23:28.492 19346-19346/com.example.lado.banksystem D/EMAILCHECK: Email passed was >>>qwerty@gmail.com<<<
03-21 21:23:28.492 19346-19346/com.example.lado.banksystem E/SQLiteLog: (1) no such column: id
03-21 21:23:28.493 19346-19346/com.example.lado.banksystem D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
03-21 21:23:28.493 19346-19346/com.example.lado.banksystem E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                         Process: com.example.lado.banksystem, PID: 19346
                                                                         android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: id (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT id FROM banksystem WHERE email =?
                                                                             at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
                                                                             at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:889)
                                                                             at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:500)
                                                                             at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
                                                                             at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
                                                                             at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.<init>(SQLiteQuery.java:37)
                                                                             at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.query(SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.java:44)
                                                                             at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1318)
                                                                             at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.queryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1165)
                                                                             at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.query(SQLiteDatabase.java:1036)
                                                                             at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.query(SQLiteDatabase.java:1204)
                                                                             at com.example.lado.banksystem.DBHandler.isEmailExists(DBHandler.java:71)
                                                                             at com.example.lado.banksystem.RegisterActivity$1.onClick(RegisterActivity.java:50)
                                                                             at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5637)
                                                                             at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22429)
                                                                             at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
                                                                             at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                             at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
                                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
                                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
```

Comment: Pls post the error log as well.

Comment: In the `isEmailExists` method, add `Log.d("EMAILCHECK","Email passed was >>>" + email + "<<<");`   as a line before the line `Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_NAME, columns, selection, selectionArgs, null, null, null);`, rerun and let us know the resultant output from the log. I suspect that there is an issue the email passed to the method.

Comment: @MikeT I added and here it is the result `3-21 21:23:28.492 19346-19346/com.example.lado.banksystem D/EMAILCHECK: Email passed was >>>qwerty@gmail.com<<<`

Comment: Try **one** of the following a) delete the App's data, b) uninstall the App or c) increase the version number (e.g. change `public static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;` to `public static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 2;`) and then rerun the App.

Comment: @MikeT id column I added in `public void onCreate()` where I created table and it's auto increment

Comment: @MikeT okay I will try

Comment: @MikeT it works thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is a common mis-conception about the `onCreate` method. That is instead of being invoked every time the Database Helper is instantiated, it is only invoked once when the database is created.

The easy fix when developing and when the underlying data does not need to be preserved is to delete the database (delete the App's data or uninstall the App), thus as the database will then be recreated the changed DB structure will be applied.

If the `onUpgrade` method will drop the table and then invoke the `onCreate` method increasing the database version number can also fix the issue.